# Duplicate records in detail section of crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working on Migration of VB windows application to C#.Net. It contains Crystal Reports coded using CRPEAuto.dll. I have upgraded them using latest Crystal Decision dll's.

I am Using the same `.prt` files(Design is not changed), and fixed some Formula issues. Now, Crystal reports are
working as expected. I am executing the Dynamic query and binding the results Dataset table to the `ReportDocument`.

I have an issue with data being loaded on reports. The results Dynamic SQL query output and the data which is being shown on reports are not same. I am getting Duplicate rows.

```
Expected Data:
Ord_ID               TO_Symbol               From_Symbol
1                         A                      --
2                         B                      --
```

There is no data for `From_Symbol` field.
Actual Report Data:

```
Ord_ID               TO_Symbol               From_Symbol
1                         A                     A
1                         A                     B
1                         B                     A
1                         B                     B
2                         A                     A
2                         A                     B
2                         B                     A
2                         B                     B
```

We have Joins in SQL query. The resultant DataSet is getting 2 rows as expected.

It seems, there was some outer join happen with in the report `data(To_Symbol and From_Symbol)` before showing the data.

I have tried in google, but now able to find the exact settings (or) Changes need to be done.

Please help me in finding the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: One way is to select option select distinct records

Comment: I already tried but in my SQL query I'm not getting duplicates records

Comment: Looks like report design has problem....can you explain are there any groups and how you design the report

Comment: Yes, there are. I created a section details for my two tables. They are linked in the report as well.